# Ошибка Notice: Use of undefined constant

Tags: php, mysql, sql

В цикле два раза подряд выполняется следующая функция:

```
function CodeToURLImg($code)
{
    $sql_catalog = 'SELECT Image FROM Message57 WHERE ItemID=' . $code;
    $query_catalog = mysql_query($sql_catalog);
    $row_catalog = mysql_fetch_array($query_catalog);
    $massiv = explode(":", $row_catalog[Image]);
    $CodeToURLImg = '/netcat_files/' . $massiv[3];
    return $CodeToURLImg;
}
```

Первый раз возвращает нормально значение, второй раз возвращает ошибку:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array()
>   expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in
>   /home/a/aas2ra/aas2ra.bget.ru/public_html/netcat/full.php(127)
>   : eval()'d code on line 101

После включения отображение ошибок также увидел вот такую вот ошибку:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant
>   Image - assumed 'Image' in
>   /home/a/aas2ra/aas2ra.bget.ru/public_html/netcat/full.php(127)
>   : eval()'d code on line 121

Оба раза значение в функцию передавалось одинаковое. Как исправить это?

Comment: Делюсь опытом:
В некоторых случаях надо в $_POST[] прописывать не строковые - `$_POST[user]`, а числовые значения - `$_POST[0]`, `$_POST[1]`.

Comment: Каким образом `$_POST` связан с вопросом?

Comment: Советую выкинуть из головы такой подход, а еще на прямую обращаться к глобальным массивам, за частую лучше воспользоваться filter_* функциями.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$massiv = explode(":",$row_catalog[Image]);
```

Поправочка. Он принимает Image за константу. Надо за-экранировать кавычками.

```
$massiv = explode(":",$row_catalog['Image']);
```

Или (что не рекомендуется) создать константу.

```
define('Image', 'Image');
$massiv = explode(":",$row_catalog[Image]);
```

Comment: Заэкранировал ее кавычками. Но основная проблема так и не прошла с Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/a/aas2ra/aas2ra.bget.ru/public_html/netcat/full.php(127) : eval()'d code on line 101
Запрос все равно не желает выполняться

Comment: Заэкранируй $code 

Вот так:

$sql_catalog = 'SELECT Image FROM Message57 WHERE ItemID="'.$code.'";';

Comment: Все ошибка пропала. Большое спасибо)